# Не запускается на API 19

Tags: android, android-studio, style

Пытаюсь запустить приложение на api 19 вылетает следующие исключение

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mandriklab.testss, PID: 19981
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mandriklab.testss/com.mandriklab.testss.View.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.mandriklab.testss.View.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:308)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.mandriklab.testss.View.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:308) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/back_edit.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080066
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3008)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3690)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:480)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.mandriklab.testss.View.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:308) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:970)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3004)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3690) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:480) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.mandriklab.testss.View.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:308) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19981 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Единственное что я изменял это в тот самый back_edit, менял я атрибут android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" вместо этого у меня был android:color="@color/white"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml ?attr/colorPrimary -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    <stroke android:width="0.5dip" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Помогите разобраться в чём тут проблема

Comment: Проблема прослеживается только на API19, после изменений?

Comment: Для 19-го нужно использовать только цвет в Drawable, или делать ссылку из стилей: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986204/cant-convert-to-color-type-0x2-error-when-inflating-layout-in-fragment-but-onl